# Removing jQuery fancyBox black bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

On [this](http://www.devideovakvrouw.nl) link the FancyBox shows the video but with black bars to the side. Also when I resize the browser black bars appear on the top. I tried everything I could find on SO and elsewhere but I can't seem to find the solution.

This is my JS setup of the FancyBox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        },
       autoSize: false,
       fitToView: true,
       maxWidth: 960,
       maxHeigth: 540,
       height: '70%',
       width: '70%',   
    });
});
</script>
```

Where do I need to look to fix this?

Comment: This cannot be done in fancybox, the problem is at the vimeo player. You can recalculate the fancybox width and height each time the page is resized and to give those values to the vimeo link

Answer (score 0):

I found if you update the width of div which class is flideo  , that would fix this problem

you coulde see the picture url below

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23971112/stackoverflow/fancybox%20black%20bar.JPG